# Could it hurt SEO to remove a WordPress plugin that lists all categories using a <select> dropdown?

Tags: seo, wordpress, html, forms, categories

I'm redesigning WP Site and there's a plugin listing all categories in select box. The option code looks like this:

```
<option class="level-0" value="2926">AAA</option>
```

Can removing this widget have negative impact on SEO?

I want to display just most popular categories and then link to different page with all the categories. Everything with classic links, which might be actually better for SEO, but not sure.